# how can convert an object to NSData in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsdata

Right now, I have a class assuming it's 

`class User ...
..`

I have an instance `User * admin = [[User alloc]init];`

I now need to convert this `admin` into `NSData`,

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NSCoding`? Why `NSData`? To `JSON`?

Comment: And admin.someInstance does contains some data which is to be convertible to NSData?

Comment: @Hamish, sorry for the confusing. I updated the edits.

Comment: @Larme, it's required to be converted to NSData

Comment: @ShaoboWang: Why does it need to be converted to `NSData`? What's the purpose?

Comment: @vaibhav, it contains some properties like int, NSData, and CLang struct.

Comment: @Larme, I am trying to make socket communications. I'd provide a function which receives a instance but returns NSData, the returned NSData will be used by other guys to send via socket.

Comment: If the other side doesn't use Objective-C/Swift, you need to find a "multiplatform protocol", which can be JSON for instace.

Comment: @Larme, thanks for you recommendation, other side is finished. The invocation is amongst the functions of OBJC. The instances to nsdata convention is required by design here.

Comment: If the other side is finished, you need to know how it deserialized the `NSData`, then convert your `User` object to the `NSData` corresponding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `NSData` for any object conforming to the `NSCoding` or  `NSSecureCoding` protocol:

```
NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourObject];
```

Converting again to actual form using `unarchiveObjectWithData`:

```
CustomCls *obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response

Comment: app crash on this don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

First take a look this [NSCoding link](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)

**Archiving your object**

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:YourClass];
```

**Unarchiving your data to object**

```
YourClass *objYourClass = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *modelData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:UserLoginDetails requiringSecureCoding:true error:nil];
NSDictionary *selectedUserLoginDetails = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSDictionary class] fromData:modelData error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", selectedUserLoginDetails);
```